# Automatically unlock desktop when approached with mobile

Tags: linux, python, security, bluetooth

I'm looking for a way to use my mobile to automatically unlock my laptop. [Blue Proximity](https://sourceforge.net/projects/blueproximity/) seemed like a good answer, but it's clearly been abandoned as a project and I'm having problems with some of the dependencies. Has anyone got this working on Ubuntu 20.04 or got an alternative?

For those who don't know: *Blue Proximity* lets you define which Bluetooth IDs are trusted, and on which signal strength ("proximity") they should trigger a desktop unlock. These are also the basic requirements for the software I'm looking for – plus of course that it must run on Ubuntu 20.04, as stated.